# Ubuntu 14 no way to install Nvidia drivers or get suspend working

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, suspend

I'm trying to get an "old" Acer Aspire 5720 operative with Ubuntu 14.04 but the proprietary drivers nor suspend work properly.

My hardware configuration:

- Intel Core Duo T5250 @ 1,5Ghz
- 4GB DDR2 RAM
- Nvidia GeForce 8400M GS 256MB
- Kingston ssdNow V300 120GB

I've tried legacy drivers ver.173, removing bumblebee, removing nouveau, resetting xorg.conf file, but nothing changes.

My aim is to get suspend working, but with nouveau installed when resuming from suspension the only thing I get is a message saying "nouveau fault", with nvidia drivers instead I get a black screen.

Is it a kernel bug, a driver bug, or is it just my fault?

Comment: What's the output when you use `ubuntu-drivers devices`?

Comment: '== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
model    : G86M [GeForce 8400M GS]
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00000427sv00001025sd0000011Ebc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
driver   : nvidia-173 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-304-updates - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-331-updates - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-331 - distro non-free recommended
driver   : nvidia-304 - distro non-free
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin'
I'm currently using nouveau but running at very low resolution.

Comment: Yeah, if you want to try the other ones that it lists you have to make sure that the other ones are removed. And can't you turn the resolution up?

Comment: I can't manage to do nothing, it doesn't work anyway. I've tried installing ubuntu 12 lts instead of 14, suspend worked but there's nothing to do with the drivers, none works.

Answer (score 1):

Finally solved! It turned out that the Nvidia GeForce 8400M GS (luckily installed as an MXM card instead of being soldered on motherboard) was defective as many other 8400M, I did the oven trick, now it works flawlessly with full hardware acceleration.

---

*The oven trick consists of removing the defective MXM GPU module and leaving it into the oven at 200°C for 10 minutes (maybe with some SMD flux under the GPU BGA, but it worked fine for me even without flux).*

Comment: What is oven trick?

Comment: The oven trick consists of emoving the defective MXM GPU module and leaving it into the oven at 200°C for 10 minutes (maybe with some SMD flux under the GPU BGA, but it worked fine for me even without flux).